# Pandas merge columns to tensor

Tags: pandas, pytorch, torch

Im trying to merge several dataframe columns containing float64 numbers into one tensor which will be stored still in the dataframe

`df[name]= df[cols].apply(lambda x: torch.tensor(list(x)),axis=1)`

this does not work properly and returns me a list of tensors.

what can I do?

Comment: provide a part of data please.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
torch.tensor(np.stack(df[cols].tolist()))
```